# Plural and Apostrophe

Tags: commas, apostrophe

My eyes are like cat's eyes.

My eyes and Jim's eyes are like cat's eyes.

My eyes and Jim's eyes are like cats' eyes.

Sentence two or three, which is correct? She is talking about her boyfriend's eyes and her eyes both.

Confused. I am a middle school student. Help.

Comment: I would use *cat eyes* in both cases. If I was to use a possessive form instead, I would use *cats' eyes* in both cases. I would not use *cat's eyes* at all in this way, not for talking about Jim and me and not even for talking about just me.

Comment: `Cat eyes` would be a mainly US English thing. Elsewhere, `cat's eyes` are those reflective things in the road that mark out lanes, or the organs that cats see with. Your eyes are like generic cat's eyes, not the eyes of many individual cats (`cats' eyes`).

Comment: A snag is that a "cat's eye" is a compound noun, referring to a reflective device on at least UK roads. Actually, the modern variant "cats eye" with plural "cats eyes" has been more widely used recently, although as the devices are being phased out, the struggle may be academic. But the possessive usage (ie the eyes of cats) needs cats' eyes. You might prefer the attributive construction instead, which Mike Graham suggests, though "cats eyes" may have crept over into literal use; it certainly _sounds_ more natural. But have you done any research? // There could well be an ambiguity!